# Installing expo-cli with EACCES symlink error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install expo-cli using `npm install -g expo-cli`, however come across this issue. I've looked at other posts and they have similar issues but the syscall seems to be different. Any solutions recommended by them does not seem to work. I believe it has something to do with how npm was installed, however unsure how to continue. Running `npm list -g` returns the following:

```
    /usr/local/lib
└─┬ npm@6.14.5
```

shouldn't that be under `/usr/local/lib/node`?

The error I get is as follows:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/expo
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/expo'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/expo'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/expo'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     path: '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js',
npm ERR!     dest: '/usr/local/bin/expo'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/expo'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/my_user_name/.npm/_logs/2020-07-07T22_13_27_629Z-debug.log
```

Comment: update: I tried installing it without the global tag, so it seems to be an issue with that actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  - `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g expo-cli`  It works for me